# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: NPE at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(1353)

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, soapfault

I have generated code using the wsdl (via IBM's JDK1.6) using wsimport command. I am also using IBM RAD as a development tool with WAS 8.5.5 as the App Server

Through a simple client program I'm able to call a webservice. However, when I integrate with my project (web application) I'm getting a javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException. Upon doing some google search and reading up on stackoverflow regarding this issue **I was suggested to delete axis2 libraries as there might be a conflict**. So I did that just to see if it would work (while it would break other stuff) but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**libraries that project uses is:**

```
axis2-adb-1.4 axis2-kernel-1.4 axiom-api-1.2.7.jar axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar commons-beanutils-1.6.1.jar commons-codec-1.11.jar commons-collections-3.0.jar commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar
commons-digester-1.5.jar commons-fileupload-1.0.jar commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar commons-lang-2.0.jar commons-logging-1.0.3.jar commons-net-1.4.0.jar commons-validator-1.0.2.jar cryptix.jar imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar
jakarta-oro.jar log4j-1.2.8.jar mex-1.4.1.jar neethi-2.0.4.jar ojdbc6.jar ABClient.jar providerutil.jar regexp.jar soap.jar struts-1.1.jar usercom.jar
wimap.jar woden-api-1.0M8.jar wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar xmisoap.jar XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
```

**Root Cause:**

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1353)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1079)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:680)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:626)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.pingClearinghouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ams.sacwis.security.SecurityAction.neiceCrap(SecurityAction.java:100)
    at com.ams.sacwis.security.SecurityAction.perform(SecurityAction.java:185)
    at com.ams.framework.action.AMSAction.execute(AMSAction.java:100)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at com.ams.framework.action.AMSRequestProcessor.process(AMSRequestProcessor.java:127)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at com.ams.framework.action.AMSActionServlet.service(AMSActionServlet.java:202)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you have a go at reformatting your post (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to improve its readability. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for editing. will try to do a better job next time